# HEC HMS and GDAL configuration on Windows

Tags: java, jython, gdal

I am trying to get hec-hms software to run a sample project as a job, following the official instructions from https://www.hec.usace.army.mil/confluence/hmsdocs/hmsguides/running-hec-hms-with-jython

when run the command :

```
hec-hms.cmd -script C:/Projects/castro/scripts/compute_current.py
```

I get this error

```
C:\Program Files\HEC\HEC-HMS\4.8>jre\bin\java -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -DMapPanel.NoVolatileImage=true -Dpython.import.site=false -Xms32M -Dpython.path=.\hms.jar;.\lib\* "-Djava.library.path=.\bin;.\bin\gdal;.\bin\hdf" -classpath .\hms.jar;.\lib\* hms.Hms  -script c:\Users\windar\Documents\castro_48.py
Native library load failed.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\HEC\HEC-HMS\4.8\bin\gdal\gdalalljni.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
Apr 21, 2021 12:56:13 PM hms.m <init>
SEVERE: 'void org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.SetConfigOption(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'void org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.SetConfigOption(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)'
        at org.gdal.gdal.gdalJNI.SetConfigOption(Native Method)
        at org.gdal.gdal.gdal.SetConfigOption(gdal.java:184)
        at hms.m.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hms.m.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at hms.Hms.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
```

I added these env variables, but it persists:

```
GDAL_DRIVER_PATH=C:/Programs/HEC-HMS-4.8/bin/gdal/gdalplugins
GDAL_DATA=C:/Programs/HEC-HMS-4.8/gdal/bin/gdal-data
PROJ_LIB=C:/Programs/HEC-HMS-4.8/gdal/bin/projlib
```

Answer (score 1):

By testing and comparing different versions, I found out that the HEc-HMS 4.8 comes with GDAL missing some DLL files.The straightforward solution is to downgrade to 4.7.1 and make sure that the project is compatible.